# Bitmap.createBitmap outofmemoryerror

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, horizontalscrollview

I have a RelativeLayout inside a HorizontalScrollView and the object is to capture the whole view (which is wider than the screen). This is what I use:

```
thelayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.thelayout);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(thelayout.getWidth(), thelayout.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
thelayout.draw(c);
```

I then display the bitmap and all is good unless the RelativeLayout has a lot of widgets, then I receive OutOfMemoryError on Bitmap.createBitmap.

In normal circumstances we could resize or compress a bitmap prior to using it, for example when the image came from the file system or camera, using Bitmap.createScaledBitmap with BitmapFactory.Options.

However as the dimensions for createBitmap has to be the RelativeLayout inside the HorizontalScrollView to ensure I capture the whole screen, I cannot find anything to to overcome the OutOfMemoryError.

Any ideas?

UPDATE

I changed to RGB_565 but still same issue. Log cat reports

```
02-12 10:11:10.897: E/AndroidRuntime(22958): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget(Heap Size=17927KB, Allocated=13569KB, Bitmap Size=1046KB)
```

However if I take allocated away from heap size I'm left with 4358. Yet bitmap size is 1046, so shouldn't it have worked, or am I not interpreting the log correctly?

Comment: Have you tried using `Config.RGB_565` instead of `Config.ARGB_8888`? This will halve the memory requirement for the bitmap.

Comment: Did not know that, I'll give it a go. I assume this will degrade the bitmap somehow?

Comment: Degrade is a strong word :) It will lower the color range available, so yes it will have an effect on the visual quality of the image. It will not however introduce any kind of artifacts or blurring in the image. The only real area that it will be highly visible in is in smooth gradients - which will become less smooth at 16-bit color.

Answer (score 0):

Note that my advice here only masks the problem, to some extent, but you can try adding the following line to your application tag in your manifest:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

For some devices, this may give you more heap space with which to allocate the Bitmap.

Comment: Hi Josh, I need to support many users who are using Android version prior to 3.0 where largeHeap flag has no effect. Thanks for the idea.